# WPF starting a new Winform Cefsharp

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, cefsharp

I've been working in WPF and trying to start a Winform from that area.  The only solution is to open it as a `ShowDialog()`.  Is this a bug or can we expect any problems in the future?
my other program is located in the same solution, but not the same namespace.

```
WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1 program2 = new WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1();
program2.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: What does the C language have to do with this question?

Comment: There is no `c#` tag, there is a `c` tag. Tags are important and should be correct. And no, I did not vote to close.

Comment: Please look at your tags. `c`, `wpf`, and `winforms`. The `c` tag is for the C programming language. Thus my question was: "What does the C language have to do with this question". This was an attempt to clarify your question and the tags.

Comment: This is why I *asked* instead of downvoting, flagging, or just making a change without clarifying your intent.

Comment: Are you saying that `.Show()` doesn't work?  I've never tried mixing them this way exactly, but that seems strange to me.

Comment: Just tested, and `winForm = new WinForm1(); winForm.Show();` works perfectly fine for me.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes Show() does not work here!

Comment: It might be a .Net 4.6.1 issue i cant role back becouse libraries i use are not supported bellow 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem... the reason `program2.Show()` was not working was becouse of Cefsharp during the launch of the second program via javascript the loading progress bar(Javascript) was not done loading. you can identify these problems with Cefsharp by tagging them in to

```
 if (browser.CanExecuteJavascriptInMainFrame)
                    {
                        WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1 program2 = new WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1();
                        program2.Show();
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested this, and it works for me:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Form winForm;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        winForm = new WinForm1();
        winForm.Show();
    }
}
```

[image]

I believe your problem is most likely due to your `program2` going out of scope immediately after you try to call `Show` on it, which is closing it faster than you can see it.  The reason `ShowDialog` works, is because it is a blocking call, keeps the window in scope and open until after it is closed.

Try declaring `program2` as a **field** within the WPF `Window` class, instead of as a local variable.  That will keep it in scope.

Comment: i should have mention it but my other program is located in the same solution, but not the same namespace.

Comment: That shouldn't affect anything.  In my test, both windows were also part of the same project.  This should work  with them in separate projects, or even when the WinForms window is coming from a referenced assembly.

Comment: It does here, when i use Show() the new program stalls/crashes, there is nothing in this program. working in 64bit... both of them.

Comment: The problem you are having must be somewhere else, and not just due to calling `Show` on a WinForms window from WPF.  I recreated that in its simplest form, and it works perfectly.  I would be happy to take a look at your project for you, if you could give me access somehow.

Comment: hmmm strange. are u sure it is not the WinformHost? i am using Visual basic 2015 .Net 4.6.1.

Comment: You never mentioned a `WinFormHost` previously.  It is possible that the problem is coming from there, but I would need more details on exactly how it is being used to know for sure.

Comment: It is not comming from there, this is my first application in WPF and you are right something else is causing it, i just build a little program the same way just the button.

Comment: My offer to help find the problem if you can send me the code still stands.  You can upload the project to github, BitBucket, or something similar, or even zip the project up and share it from google drive or some other service.

Comment: Its CefSharp/Javascript Hybrid. i will try and tacle it my self first, it might be caused by Cefsharp, i will modify the topic and post the solution when i have found the problem, letting others do the work for you never helps in the long run, i have not met any one who did not run in to problems developing applications.

Comment: I found the problem, it was Cefsharp related Browser was not ready to launch.